# Rails API route Resources wrong response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a Ruby on Rails 5.2.4 running on Ruby 2.6.6. The frontend expects that the data returned by the backend is a JSON structured on: "resources" (if there is a list of data) or "recource" if there is only one data.

The app was created for Rails 5.0 and I made some updates so it will work well on Rails 5.2 also. Maybe I missed something.

The routes.rb looks like:

```
resources :route_a, only: [:index, :show]
resources :route_b, only: [:index]
resources :route_c, only: [:create]
resource  :route_d, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
...
resources :route_e, only: [] do
  resource :route_f, only: [] do
    post 'route_g', on: :member
  end
end
```

The frontend Javascript framework expects the returned data to contain a "resources" or "resource" key. But in 80% of cases the data doesn't return the resources/resource structured JSON. What is wrong with Rails? Is this issue related to a gem, to the database? Why for some routes the response is returned in a resources/resource structured data and for other routes the plain JSON is returned?

Instad of a response such as:

```
[{"id":33,"type":"M..
```

I need to have:

```
[{"resources":{"id":33,"type":"M...
```

I'm new to Rails, sorry for probably asking basic things, but I don't know what's the issue here. Thank you.

**Important**

I have a file: `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb` that contains:

```
# Enable parameter wrapping for JSON. You can disable this by setting :format to an empty array.
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: [:json]
end

# To enable root element in JSON for ActiveRecord objects.
# ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
#   self.include_root_in_json = true
# end
```

**Important 2**

This is the `/api/integrations` page controller:

```
class IntegrationsController < ApiController

def index
    integrations = policy_scope(Integration)
    integrations = integrations.where(type: params[:type_eq]) if params[:type_eq]
    render_resources integrations, ransack_query: params[:q]
  end
end
```

The `api/integrations` response is:

```
[{"id":254,"name":"Integration 1"...
```

The result doesn't contain any `resources` key inside. I described the `render_resources` method below:

```
def render_resources(resources, options = {})
    options[:pagination] = true if options[:pagination].nil?
    pagination = options.delete(:pagination)
    ransack_query = options.delete(:ransack_query) || {}
    ransack_sort = options.delete(:ransack_sort) || params[:sort]

    resources = resources.ransack(ransack_query.to_hash.merge(s: ransack_sort)).result if ransack_sort || ransack_query.any?

    total = resources.respond_to?(:total_count) ? resources.total_count : resources.length
    default = {root: :resources, meta: {total: total}}
    results = pagination ? resources.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page]) : resources
    results = results.includes(options[:includes]) if options[:includes]
    render({json: results}.merge(default).merge(options))
  end
```

Since this method doesn't return anymore the response containing a `resources` key, am I right to say that it's because of the implied libraries - Ransack and Pagination? Because up until I updated ruby and rails gems, the functionality worked as expected. Still, I don't know what is the library that should structure the response's JSON data in a `resources` or `resource` key.

Comment: I suspect you're using ActionModelSerializers or something like that and something has changed in the updates. I suggest checking if the structure of resources has changed (e.g. new/missing keys). Other than that try changing the last line of `render_resource` to `render {json: {resources: results, meta: {total: total}}}.merge(options)`.

Comment: I will check. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you went straight from rails 5.0 to 5.2 you might have skipped fixing some deprecation warnings present in 5.1. Same situation with ruby upgrades - unless you have vast test coverage and everything works fine - it's better to go one minor (5.0->5.1->5.2) version at a time.

Also during rails upgrade other gems are also upgraded, each new version of each gem might have some breaking changes (or new bugs)

If you're using active_model_serializers - you might have effects from their changes to default adapter ([now it's](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/909) `json_api`) and other movement around `root` option, see [changelog for 0.10](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/CHANGELOG-0-10.md) and previous changelogs depending on version you're upgrading from

Comment: Also, it might pay off to lock the version of the gems to what they were at 5.0, and try upgrading Rails to 5.1 first, then each gem in turn.

Comment: I believe that I made the mistake of upgrading from 5.0 to 5.2.4.2 (latest). I will check the changelog for 0.10 as you pointed in your reply. Many thanks!

Comment: Rails doesn't follow standard SemVer. Patch level updates require some work.